# using <? echo$item->getImage().'-1.jpg'?> to get an image name from a database

Tags: php

in my code i used

```
<img class='container  card-body furniture-size' src="../FurnitureImages/<? echo$item->getImage().'-1.jpg'?>"
```

but when i test it the image name is

```
<?%20echo%20$item->getImage().%27-1.jpg%27%20?>
```

instead of

```
"furniture1-1.jpg"
```

the section with the code is:

```
    <div class="center-align  main-side furniture-box " style="float: right">
       <h1 class="w-100 p-5 pulse text-white" >Furniture</h1>
        <div class="col-sm-12 row" style="margin-left: 175px">
            <?php foreach ($view->searchResult as $item) { ?>
                <div class='furniture-box border-white  col-sm-4 pt-2 pb-3 m-1' style='float: right; color:#fff; background:#9fa9a3'>
                    <?php echo $item->getFurnitureName()?>

                    <img class="container  card-body furniture-size'" src="../FurnitureImages/<?php echo $item->getImage() . '-1.jpg'; ?>"/>

                    Color: <?php echo $item->getFurnitureColour()?>
                    <br>
                    <a href="/viewItem.php?itemId=<?php echo $item->getFurnitureId()?>" class="btn btn-dark">View to Bid</a>
                </div>
            <?php }?>
        </div>
       
     </div>
```

can anyone help me fix this please?

Comment: Use `<?php echo $item->getImage() . '-1.jpg'; ?>"` does that work better

Comment: If short tags are disabled in your php.ini (which they have been as default since many PHP versions back), you need to use `<?php` instead of only `<?` since PHP will then ignore those and echo that as text. The only exception is for the short way of echoing: `<?= $item->getImage()...` which always works.

Comment: Still same problem i tried enabling short tags in php.ini didn't work, then i added <?php and that made the entire div disappear

Comment: Then maybe it would be useful if you show us More of this section of code so we can see whats going on

Comment: I have just added the section to my question

Comment: Looks as though `$view->searchResult` isn't returning any results and short tags aren't enabled. Which is why it shows the _plain text_  when you tried the code with short codes and removes the content entirely when using _complete_ tags. Try to `var_dump($view->searchResult);` and see what happens...

Comment: I just used var_dump and it returns everything how i want it apart from the image